# How do I modify the gcloud sdk to be logged in indefinitely?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a google compute instance which hosts a computationally rigorous program. The machine is quite expensive so we would only like the machine to be on when it is in use. However, it is inefficient for the company to have a physical person turn the machine on and off every time a user wants to run some samples through the program.

My solution would be to use the gcloud sdk to turn the machine on and off using a bash script every time someone submits samples through a wrapper program (GUI web interface) I have written to abstract users from having to use the command line.

The issue is that gcloud logs out after some period of inactivity which defeats the purpose. The whole idea is to remove the human component, and not rely on an individual from having to be involved. Especially if someone in the company has a eureka moment at say 2AM, there will be no one online then to start the instance. How can I extend gcloud sdk to be logged in indefinitely.

I have tried to follow these instructions:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756?hl=en

Unfortunately it says sessions can only be set to max 24hrs which isnt useful at all, how can I bypass this?

Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhoud That is why I am asking, there must be a way to get around this, I am sure I am not the only person who has thought of this, otherwise I should just apply to become a google engineer, as I have come up with a use case that not even their geniuses have thought of!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), which has static long-lived credentials, and grant it whatever roles are necessary to shut down the machine.

- https://pnatraj.medium.com/how-to-run-gcloud-command-line-using-a-service-account-f39043d515b9